# Trying to recreate the working java encryption method in nodejs

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, encryption

I have a working Java code for encryption of string in `AES` encryption using the `key` , and i have been trying the replicate the code in `Nodejs` for quite long but unable to get the exact `encrypted hash` output as Java code gives me. Please let me know what i have been doing wrong.

Encrypt.java

```
    @Component
    public class WebSecurity {

        @Autowired
        Environment env;
        private SecretKeySpec skeySpec;
        private Cipher cipher;

        public WebSecurity() {
            skeySpec = null;
            cipher = null;
        }

        public void initEncrypt(String key) throws Exception {
            try {
                skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(HexUtil.HexfromString(key), "AES");
                cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
                cipher.init(1, skeySpec);
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException nsae) {
                throw new Exception("Invalid Java Version");
            } catch (NoSuchPaddingException nse) {
                throw new Exception("Invalid Key");
            }
        }

        public String encrypt(String message,String enc_key) throws Exception {
            try {
                initEncrypt(enc_key);

                byte encstr[] = cipher.doFinal(message.getBytes());
                String encData = HexUtil.HextoString(encstr);
                return java.net.URLEncoder.encode(encData);
            } catch (BadPaddingException nse) {
                throw new Exception("Invalid input String");
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            System.out.println(new WebSecurity().encrypt("Charcoal Integration", "key here"));
        }

    }
```

Hexutil.java is the file where all the magic is happening and i am unable to replicate the same in nodejs.

```
    public class HexUtil {

        public HexUtil() {
        }

        public static byte[] HexfromString(String s) {
            int i = s.length();
            byte abyte0[] = new byte[(i + 1) / 2];
            int j = 0;
            int k = 0;
            if (i % 2 == 1)
                abyte0[k++] = (byte) HexfromDigit(s.charAt(j++));
            while (j < i)
                abyte0[k++] = (byte) (HexfromDigit(s.charAt(j++)) << 4 | HexfromDigit(s.charAt(j++)));
            return abyte0;
        }

        public static int HexfromDigit(char c) {
            if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
                return c - 48;
            if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F')
                return (c - 65) + 10;
            if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f')
                return (c - 97) + 10;
            else
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid hex digit: " + c);
        }

        public static String HextoString(byte abyte0[], int i, int j) {
            char ac[] = new char[j * 2];
            int k = 0;
            for (int l = i; l < i + j; l++) {
                byte byte0 = abyte0[l];
                ac[k++] = hexDigits[byte0 >>> 4 & 0xf];
                ac[k++] = hexDigits[byte0 & 0xf];
            }
            return new String(ac);
        }

        public static String HextoString(byte abyte0[]) {
            return HextoString(abyte0, 0, abyte0.length);
        }

        private static final char hexDigits[] = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' };

    }
```

This is the nodejs code that i have tried.

Encrypt.js

```
    let crypto = require('crypto');
    var util= require('util');

    var encoder=new util.TextEncoder();

    var encryptKey = function (text, algorithm) {
            var cipher = crypto.createCipher(algorithm, HexfromString('a4e11920212a47d85358bb86ba75abcd').toString('hex'));
            // console.log(HexfromString('a4e11920212a47d85358bb86ba750f37').toString('binary'))

            // var encstr = cipher.final(text).toString(2);

            // console.log(test);
            var abc=text.split('').map(s);
            // console.log('abc : ',(abc[0] >>> 0).toString(2))
            var crypted = cipher.update(HextoString(encoder.encode(String(text).getBytes())),'utf8', 'hex')
            crypted += cipher.final('hex');
            return crypted;

    }
    function s(x) {return x.charCodeAt(0);}


    var HexfromString = function(s){
            var i = s.length;
            var abyte0 = [(i + 1) / 2];
            var j = 0;
            var k = 0;
            if (i % 2 == 1){
                abyte0[k++] =  HexfromDigit(new Buffer(s.charAt(j++)));
            }
            while (j < i){
                // console.log('hex : ',HexfromDigit(s.charAt(j++)).toString(2))
                abyte0[k++] = (HexfromDigit(s.charAt(j++)) << 4 | HexfromDigit(s.charAt(j++))).toString(2)

            }
            return abyte0;
    }

    function getSignedInteger(bits) {
        return bits.length === 8 && +bits[0]
            ? ~(parseInt(bits, 2) ^ 255)
            : parseInt(bits, 2);
    }

    var HexfromDigit = function(a) {
        var c = a.charCodeAt(0);
        // console.log('a: ',a, ' c : ',c);
            if (c >= '0'.charCodeAt(0) && c <= '9'.charCodeAt(0))
                return c - 48;
            if (c >= 'A'.charCodeAt(0) && c <= 'F'.charCodeAt(0))
                return (c - 65) + 10;
            if (c >= 'a'.charCodeAt(0) && c <= 'f'.charCodeAt(0))
                return (c - 97) + 10;
            else
                console.log('invalid hex digit', c)
        }

    var HextoStrings = function(abyte0, i, j) {
        console.log(abyte0)
            var tempArr=[j * 2]
            var k = 0;
            for (var l = i; l < j; l++) {
                var byte0 = abyte0[l];
                tempArr[k++] = hexDigits[byte0 >>> 4 & 0xf];
                tempArr[k++] = hexDigits[byte0 & 0xf];
                // console.log(hexDigits[byte0 >>> 4 & 0xf])
                // console.log(tempArr, k)
            }
            // console.log(tempArr);
            return  String(tempArr);
        }


    var HextoString = function(abyte0) {
            return HextoStrings(abyte0, 0, abyte0.length);
        }

    // var hexDigits = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    var hexDigits = [ '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' ];

    var valEncrypt = encryptKey('charcoaleats', 'aes-256-ecb');
    var encodedEnVal = encodeURI(valEncrypt);
    console.log( 'encrypt : ',encodedEnVal );
```

Key Used : `a4e1112f45e84f785358bb86ba750f48`

String To Be Encrypted : `maharastra`

Expected Hash Output : `81FD9101751D3F6632C0372E4BE257D1`

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: The **magic** is in a hex encoder? Oh dear. Why not just get a pre-made hex encoder/decoder (i.e. codec)? You may need to prefix a `0`character if the number of hex digits is odd.

Comment: Or simply use the built-in node cipher class? https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_class_cipher

Comment: @MaartenBodewes thanx ,in js we have `Buffer.from` method to convert string to hex , bt i am unable to generate the proper hex from the array , any code wld help me alot

Comment: OK, tested that for you, the hex encoding / decoding is not failing for the Java code. So you just need to create or implement a hex encoder. This is definitely wrong: `abyte0[k++] =  new Buffer(HexfromDigit(s.charAt(j++)));`

Comment: @MaartenBodewes i have been following you , `Buffer.from()` method in nodejs gives me proper hex encoding of the key , still stucked at providing the proper buffer to hextoString

Comment: Why not use `Buffer#toString('hex')` while you're at it and get rid of the mess for once and for all?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes , i think now i getting the proper buffered output for my key `[-44, -47,-39,-16,-15,-736,-41,-40,-45,-40,0,-42, 0,-11,-768,-9 ]` , but still the `HexToString` method is not working properly , givinng long hex nowhere close to expected

Comment: Have you tried `Buffer#toString('hex')` already?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207996/discussion-between-rahul-sharma-and-maarten-bodewes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let crypto = require('crypto');

var iv = new Buffer.from('');   //(null) iv 
var algorithm = 'aes-256-ecb';
var password = 'a4e1112f45e84f785358bb86ba750f48';      //key password for cryptography

function encrypt(buffer){
    var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm,new Buffer(password),iv)
    var crypted = Buffer.concat([cipher.update(buffer),cipher.final()]);
    return crypted;
}

console.log(encrypt(new Buffer('TextToEncrypt')).toString())
```

Comment: Hey @rahul were you able to get this working, I am having same trouble as you. Wanted to check the final solution for this ?